# Java start python process

Tags: java, python

I'm trying to start a python script via java and send the data via socket back to the java program.
My problem is that when I start the python script after the SocketServer is created with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python3 ~/Documents/sensor/sensorADC.py");`
no connection is established and no data is transmitted.

But when I start the script manually via CLI, everything works fine.

The timing of the program start shouldn't be the problem, because I already tried different ways and orders.

The java program is a javaFx application.
EDIT: tested in Linux

2nd Edit:
    `private void startPythonScript () {
        try {
            measureProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python3 ~/Documents/sensor/sensorADC.py")); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }`

What am I missing?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Add a try-catch to see whether there are some exceptions thrown but ignored while running this command string?

Comment: The call is already wrapped in a try-catch block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solved" it.
I compiled it with pyinstaller and now it works. Python seems to be the problem here.
But I don't know why....

For others I compiled it to an executable with `pyinstaller --onefile sensor.py`

Answer (score 0):

You're close, you can pass an array to the exec method, like this:

```
String[] cmd = { "python3", "sensorADC.py", "~/Documents/sensor/"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

and it should work.

Comment: What is your meaning of splitting the conmand string into an array with "wrong" order?

Comment: That has no effect at all.